# Enhance vs. deteriorate: more of a bad thing

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

Google defines "enhance" as

> intensify, increase, or further improve the quality, value, or extent of

Consider the sentence

> (something) is enhanced

I fear this sentence will be interpreted as "there is more (something), and this is a good thing".

On the other hand, "deteriorate" is defined as

> become progressively worse.
>   synonyms:   worsen, get worse, decline, be in decline, degenerate, decay;

Some of these synonyms, notably "decline", suggest a reduction.
So the alternative sentence

> (something) is deteriorated

could be interpreted as "there is less (something), and this is a bad thing".

Is there a similar elegant way to express "there is *more* (something), and this is a *bad* thing"?

Comment: Neither of those words *primarily* refer to quantity, so neither will elegantly express the idea of there being more which is better.

Comment: A word for deterioration over a period of time is *decay*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take your understanding of *enhance* and *deteriorate* as the background, and this part: ***"Is there a similar elegant way to express 'there is more (something), and this is a bad thing'?"*** as the real problem. And this problem is about expressiveness in writing (and/or speaking). In other words, it's about how to sound more natural, more idiomatic, and have a good writing style.

In my opinion, you may be asking the wrong question. There might be a stock phrase in your first language for "there is more X and this is a bad thing" whatever X is. (I don't know this, but because you're asking this, it suggests that this might be true.)

As far as I can see, English is not like that. In English, a) some words usually go together, which means that we don't have a universal phrase that works in all cases of X, and b) when it's general enough, the connotation of "this is a bad thing" is not in the phrase, but in X itself.

Here are some examples.
a) When the noun (i.e., X) dictates the verb:

> *Viruses multiply.
>
>   Health deteriorates.
>
>   Problems escalate.
>
>   Poverty is widespread.*

b) General phrases, but the connotation of "bad thing" is in X, not the verb:

> *Weeds grow.* (But kids grow, too.)
>   *The debt increases/grows/rises/soars*. (But profit rises, too.)
>   *Bad news kept coming in.* (But money can keep coming in, too.)

bonus) Some other phrases that's usually used when we have a lot or more of X and it's a bad thing. This is not strictly the case you seem to describe in your question, though:

> *Wars are everywhere.
>
>   Things worsen.*

Answer (score 0):

> enhance
>   deteriorate

refer to the "quality" of *something* not the quantity

> The patient's condition has *deteriorated*.
>   *the patient's condition has become worse*
>   *the patient's condition has become less than what it was*
>
> The new software has *enhanced* graphics.
>   *the new software has better graphics than the previous version*

When *something* is *enhanced* it implies it is improved, when *something deteriorates* it implied it is worsened. Neither of those words imply the size of the enhancement or deterioration.

> catastrophic

is *something* which is large, sudden, and bad.

> Fukushima, Chernobyl, and Three Mile Island are examples of *catastrophic* failure for nuclear power plants.
>
> Flight LMI2933 ran out of fuel and the results were *catastrophic*.